# R: Conditionally extract data from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have two dataframes and I want to conditionally extract data from one column of one dataframe and put it into a new columnn of another datafrmae.

dataframe 1 looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date.start = c("2019-06-10 11:52:00",
  "2019-06-11 11:52:00", "2019-06-12 11:51:00"), date.end =
  c("2019-06-10 11:53:00", "2019-06-11 11:53:00", "2019-06-12 11:53:00"))
```

dataframe 2 looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(date.start = c("2019-06-11 11:50:00",
  "2019-06-10 11:51:00", "2019-06-12 11:50:00"), date.end =
  c("2019-06-11 11:54:00", "2019-06-11 08:59:00", "2019-06-12 11:57:00"),
  day = c(1, 15, 64))
```

If the `date.start` and `date.end` of df.1 fall within the `date.start` or `date.end` of any row of `df2` I want to extract the variable `day` from `df2` and put it in to the matching row of `df1`.

The expected outcome looks like this:

```
expected.out <- data.frame(date.start = c("2019-06-10 11:52:00", "2019-06-11 11:52:00", "2019-06-12 11:51:00"),
                           date.end = c("2019-06-10 11:53:00", "2019-06-11 11:53:00", "2019-06-12 11:53:00"),
                           day = c(15, 1, 64))
```

I currently have the following loop that works, but it is very slow when I run it on my large dataframe (rows = 1135133), and I am wondering if there is a faster way of doing this.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  find.match <- which(df1$date.start[i] >= df2$date.start &
                        df1$date.end[i] <= df2$date.end)
  if(length(find.match) !=0){
    df1$day[i] <- df2$day[find.match]
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` inside `sapply` to get the first row of `df2` where the dates are indside the given time range.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.POSIXct) #Convert character to POSIXct
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2], as.POSIXct)

df1$day <- df2$day[sapply(asplit(df1, 1), function(x) {match(TRUE,
 x[1] >= df2[,1] & x[2] <= df2[,2])})]
df1
#           date.start            date.end day
#1 2019-06-10 11:52:00 2019-06-10 11:53:00  15
#2 2019-06-11 11:52:00 2019-06-11 11:53:00   1
#3 2019-06-12 11:51:00 2019-06-12 11:53:00  64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is much faster than the loop I have been using!

Answer (score 3):

use `library(fuzzyjoin)`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- data.frame(
  date.start = c("2019-06-10 11:52:00", "2019-06-11 11:52:00", "2019-06-12 11:51:00"),
  date.end = c("2019-06-10 11:53:00", "2019-06-11 11:53:00", "2019-06-12 11:53:00"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(date.start = c("2019-06-11 11:50:00", "2019-06-10 11:51:00", "2019-06-12 11:50:00"),
                  date.end = c("2019-06-11 11:54:00", "2019-06-11 08:59:00", "2019-06-12 11:57:00"),
                  day = c(1, 15, 64), stringsAsFactors = F)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ymd_hms)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ymd_hms)) %>% 
  as_tibble()


fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("date.start", "date.end"), match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  date.start.x        date.end.x          date.start.y        date.end.y            day
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2019-06-10 11:52:00 2019-06-10 11:53:00 2019-06-10 11:51:00 2019-06-11 08:59:00    15
2 2019-06-11 11:52:00 2019-06-11 11:53:00 2019-06-11 11:50:00 2019-06-11 11:54:00     1
3 2019-06-12 11:51:00 2019-06-12 11:53:00 2019-06-12 11:50:00 2019-06-12 11:57:00    64
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

not sure if the method is fast

Answer (score 2):

Using `between` from `data.table` with `outer`. The `which.max` scans for the `TRUE` value in the matching matrix.

```
library(data.table)
FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) all(between(unlist(df1[x, ]), df2[y, 1], df2[y, 2])))
res <- transform(df1, day=df2[apply(outer(1:3, 1:3, FUN), 1, which.max), 3])
res
#            date.start            date.end day
# 1 2019-06-10 11:52:00 2019-06-10 11:53:00  15
# 2 2019-06-11 11:52:00 2019-06-11 11:53:00   1
# 3 2019-06-12 11:51:00 2019-06-12 11:53:00  64
```

You may want to convert to `POSIXct` format beforehand to apply solution.

```
df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.POSIXct)
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2], as.POSIXct)
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(date.start = structure(c(1560160320, 1560246720, 
1560333060), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), date.end = structure(c(1560160380, 
1560246780, 1560333180), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(date.start = structure(c(1560246600, 1560160260, 
1560333000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), date.end = structure(c(1560246840, 
1560236340, 1560333420), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    day = c(1, 15, 64)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```